# How to parameterize logins when executing SQL from PowerShell command

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, powershell

**How do we  run `CREATE LOGIN ...` against a variable string?**

[image]

I'm executing the following command:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database 'master' -Username $DBAdminAccount -Password $DBAdminPassword -Variable $SqlVariables -InputFile $ArtifactStagingDirectory\MasterDBSetup.sql
```

**MasterDBSetup.sql:**

```
....
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name  FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = '$(SvcRRRComparisonUser)')
    BEGIN 
        CREATE LOGIN '$(SvcRRRComparisonUser)' WITH PASSWORD = '$(RRRComparisonUserPassword)'
    END
....
```

**How do we run `CREATE LOGIN ...` against `$(SvcRRRComparisonUser)` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `$SqlVariables`:

```
$SqlVariables = @("SvcRRRComparisonUser='user1',RRRComparisonUserPassword='pass1'")
```

Then in the SQL file:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name  FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name = $(SvcRRRComparisonUser)
BEGIN 
    CREATE LOGIN $(SvcRRRComparisonUser) WITH PASSWORD = $(RRRComparisonUserPassword)
END
```